# How to load audio file from resource folder?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am facing issue with loading file from resource folder.
I tried the following approaches, both the cases its failing to load file from resources folder

```
val inputStream: Source[ByteString, Any] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("libapp/src/it/resources/hello.wav"))

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: libapp/src/it/resources/hello.wav
```

2nd approach I tried is using

```
val url = getClass.getResource("hello.wav")
val sourceFilePath = Paths.get(url.getPath)
val inputStream = FileIO.fromPath(sourceFilePath)

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/opt/docker/lib/com.test.libapp--1.0.jar!/hello.wav
```

Comment: Try the following: `FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("hello.wav").toURI))`

Comment: i tried this still i see java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/opt/docker/lib/com.test.libapp--1.0.jar!/hello.wav

Comment: Are you sure your jar has the file inside?

Comment: yes jar has hello.wav file

Comment: @Duelist One more thing, i can load text file using                                                   val inputStream: InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")
    val decoder             = Codec.UTF8.decoder
    val fileData = ByteString(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)(decoder).getLines.mkString). Problem is only with .wav file which is present in the same location as hello.txt file